# Handling Url Rewriting for Postback in the ServeltFilter

Tags: java, jsf, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

We have a servelt filter that is used to rewrite the urls in the format
/app/customer/1/edit forwarding to /pages/customer/customer-edit.xhtml

This works fine. However on button click to save the record the original dirty url is displayed and when I change the filter ignore "POST" requests, nothing happens and the request does not reach the button's action method.

```
if(!"POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {           
    request.getRequestDispatcher(getDirtyUrl()).forward(request, response);  
}
```

getDirtyUrl() simply sends the actual page. If I add a else to the above, and do chain.doFilter(request, response); the same page get reloaded the view building on top. It does not proceed to the button action

I need to

1. Keep the nice url in the browser after postback (button clicks)
2. Call the action method of the button

I know I can use PrettyFaces or tuckey UrlRewriteFilter but I need to get this filter working for R&D purposes as well as company requests.

If someone can point me in a direction how to solve this issue or a useful tutorial, it's greatly appreciated

Comment: Please share you code for more clarification.

Comment: I added a the filter that forwards the requests and explained further. Let me know if you want more information

Comment: _"I know I can use PrettyFaces or tuckey UrlRewriteFilter but I need to get this filter working for R&D purposes as well as company requests. "_ Care to elaborate on why e.g. PrettyFaces cannot be used then? You might otherwise just take the PrettyFaces source and modify that if it is not sufficient (instead of fully developing your own implementation)

Comment: Well the idea is to find out why this filter does not work. As a learning exercise, I want to find out how to handle post-back requests

Comment: Look at the source of PrettyFaces or OmniFaces... great examples.